# How can I place Hotkey bindings at the start/top of an autoexecuting script rather than the end?

Tags: autohotkey

Normally, "After the script has been loaded, [AutoHotKey] begins executing at the top line, continuing until a Return, Exit, hotkey/hotstring label, or the physical end of the script is encountered (whichever comes first)."

However, I would like to place my hotkey triggers *above* the Auto-execute section, for ease of readability and/or to make it simpler for end users to edit the hotkeys to their liking. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Simply give your Auto-execute section a label, and use a `goto` command just before your first hotkey bind to skip over parsing these hotkeys as part of the Auto-execute.

Example:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

UserVariableOne := 3.14
UserVariableTwo := true
UserVariableThree := "Banana"

goto BeginTheScript

^Space::
Msgbox, I am a Hotkeyed Messagebox! %UserVariableOne%
return

+Space::
Msgbox, I am another Hotkeyed Messagebox! %UserVariableTwo%
return

Esc::Exitapp

BeginTheScript:
Msgbox, I am an Auto-execute Messagebox! %UserVariableThree%
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, all you need is to put a return statement at the beginning of your script

With the example:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

UserVariableOne := 3.14
UserVariableTwo := true
UserVariableThree := "Banana"

return ; <---This line here<<

^Space::
Msgbox, I am a Hotkeyed Messagebox! %UserVariableOne%
return

+Space::
Msgbox, I am another Hotkeyed Messagebox! %UserVariableTwo%
return

Esc::Exitapp
```

[Source](https://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/auto-execute-section.html#:%7E:text=When%20an%20AutoHotkey%20script%20launches,called%20the%20auto%2Dexecute%20section.)

Comment: That `return` is extraneous. The script will parse a `return` anyway when it hits the `^Space::` line, thus preventing any further auto-execution of code below the hotkeys. The point of my answer was to allow auto-execution of code BELOW hotkeys for whatever reason, not to stop auto-execution.